# how to use #ifdef with an OR condition?

Tags: c, macros

Sorry for asking very basic question. I would like to set OR condition in #ifdef directive.?
How to do that ?
I tried

```
#ifdef LINUX | ANDROID
...
..
#endif
```

It did not work? What is the proper way?

Comment: If you're using `|` for "or" in your C conditionals too, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hence the visit to SO to find out how to do it not-wrong.

Answer (score 611, accepted):

Like this

```
#if defined(LINUX) || defined(ANDROID)
```

Answer (score 70):

## OR condition in #ifdef

```
#if defined LINUX || defined ANDROID
// your code here
#endif /* LINUX || ANDROID */
```

or-

```
#if defined(LINUX) || defined(ANDROID)
// your code here
#endif /* LINUX || ANDROID */
```

Both above are the same, which one you use simply depends on your taste.

---

**P.S.**: `#ifdef` is simply the short form of `#if defined`, however, does not support complex condition.

---

**Further-**

- AND: `#if defined LINUX && defined ANDROID`
- XOR: `#if defined LINUX ^ defined ANDROID`