# How do I check if one of multiple macros is defined in a single #ifdef?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have some C++ code, and want to perform an action if the `__APPLE__` or `__linux` macros are defined.

If I did it as a normal `if` conditional, it would be easy using `||`:

```
if (something || something) { .. code .. }
```

But as of what I know there is no `||` operator for `#ifdef` statements. How would I check if `__APPLE__` or `__linux` is defined using a single `#ifdef` statement?

Comment: Well, if thinking "available on OS X/iOS and Linux", don't you want to check for POSIX-availablity instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use #ifdef with an OR condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682593/how-to-use-ifdef-with-an-or-condition)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't in a single `#ifdef` would a single `#if` do instead?

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux)
```

this also works if you prefer

```
#if defined __APPLE__ || defined __linux
```

Answer (score 3):

In my C++ there is.

```
#if defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux)
  // ...
#endif
```