# iOS Combine preprocessor ifdef elif

Tags: ios

Currently, I am writing color scheme for different configuration like this. I can't combine like that because I got warning. How shall I do? My one is for iOS.  I have tried like this too but not okay.

```
#ifdef defined(DEBUG) || defined(STAGING) || defined(RELEASE)
```

> Extra token at the end of ifdef

```
#ifdef DEBUG || STAGING || RELEASE

// Color Code
#define COLOR_HIGHLIGHT 0x057f69
#define COLOR_SEPERATOR 0xCCCCCC
#define COLOR_SEPERATOR_FEEDS 0xE6E6E6
#define COLOR_PRIMARY_TEXT 0x333333
#define COLOR_SECONDARY_TEXT 0x999999
#define COLOR_PROFILE_TEXT 0x666666
#define COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR 0xf1f1f1
#define COLOR_CATEGORY_DISPLAY 0xe7e7e7
#define COLOR_BLACK 0x000000
#define COLOR_WHITE 0xFFFFFF
#define COLOR_SHARE_BORDER 0xededed
#define COLOR_HUD 0xCCCCCC
#define COLOR_PROFILE_BORDER 0xE1E1E1

#elif DEBUG_SMRT

// Color Code
#define COLOR_HIGHLIGHT 0xed192f
#define COLOR_SEPERATOR 0xCCCCCC
#define COLOR_SEPERATOR_FEEDS 0xE6E6E6
#define COLOR_PRIMARY_TEXT 0x333333
#define COLOR_SECONDARY_TEXT 0x999999
#define COLOR_PROFILE_TEXT 0x666666
#define COLOR_NAVIGATION_BAR 0xf1f1f1
#define COLOR_CATEGORY_DISPLAY 0xe7e7e7
#define COLOR_BLACK 0x000000
#define COLOR_WHITE 0xFFFFFF
#define COLOR_SHARE_BORDER 0xededed
#define COLOR_HUD 0xCCCCCC
#define COLOR_PROFILE_BORDER 0xE1E1E1

#endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use #ifdef with an OR condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682593/how-to-use-ifdef-with-an-or-condition)

Comment: amm..no. My one is for iOS and I have used like that and I still got warning.

Comment: try it like this `#if defined` instead of `#ifdef defined`

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C? The way `#if` and `#ifdef` directives work is different in the 2 languages. (In Objective-C `#ifdef` is a preprocessor directive, just like in C. In Swift it's actually syntax built into the language.)

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan thanks. it work